# multiple asp.net core project have problems in docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I used Visual Studio 2019 and created my dockerfile with it.
my docker file

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BackEnd.service.api.csproj", "BackEnd.service.api"]
COPY ["src/BackEnd.Service.Application/BackEnd.Service.Application.csproj", "src/BackEnd.Service.Application/"]
COPY ["src/BackEnd.Service.Model/BackEnd.Service.Model.csproj", "src/BackEnd.Service.Model/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/BackEnd.service.api/BackEnd.service.api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/BackEnd.service.api"
RUN dotnet build "BackEnd.service.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "BackEnd.service.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BackEnd.service.api.dll"]
```

and my project tree:

[image]

now I have this error:

[image]

please help me to how can I change my route of project to build it in docker?

Comment: Do you want to debug with Visual Studio as well? Because as far as I understand [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019#debugging), it seems to me that your project structure might not work with fast mode.

Comment: @mu88 I had problem in visual studio.because my windows is 8.1 single language and I couldn't set local group

Comment: Is it an option for you to change your Solution structure? Because I suspect the `src` folder might be a problem for VS. If you want I could provide you an example

Comment: @mu88 I changed but my vs have a problem CTC1010

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely your build context. Visual Studio seems to be using you web app project as the build context, meaning it can't access your Application and Model projects from the `src` folder.
I can suggest that you try to explicitly set the Dockerfile context in your web app's `.csproj` file with the following property to the `src` directory from which all projects are accessible:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <DockerfileContext>..\</DockerfileContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you may need to update your Dockerfile to point to your reference projects (Application and Model) to be relative towards the `src` folder.

```
COPY ["BackEnd.service.api/BackEnd.service.api.csproj", "src/BackEnd.service.api"]
COPY ["BackEnd.Service.Application/BackEnd.Service.Application.csproj", "src/BackEnd.Service.Application/"]
COPY ["BackEnd.Service.Model/BackEnd.Service.Model.csproj", "src/BackEnd.Service.Model/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/BackEnd.service.api/BackEnd.service.api.csproj"
```

You may need to play around with the directories a bit, but its very important to remember that the build context is the key.

Alternatively you can try to add a `docker-compose` project to your solution and have that build your Dockerfile. You will be able to specify a build context in the `docker-compose.yml` file for each project that should be built.

Comment: Please see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019) for more options that you can add to your `.csproj` file:

Answer (score 0):

I suggest follow this article [aspnetcore-app-dockerfiles](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-app-dockerfiles/) to make `dockerfile` manually instead of vs project's docker template. Also, use `.dockerignore` will help you simplify your `dockerfile` script, ignore files might not need runtime.

Here is an example from my project, hope helps.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish "src/BackEnd.service.api/BackEnd.service.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BackEnd.service.api.dll"]
```